# How to express my products in lower hierarchy as a % of total sales in PowerBi Dax

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

Hi I have issues trying to express my products in the lower hierarchy as a % of total sales in my report. Example as below in the form of a table in Power Bi:

Category
Drinks Total $100k

Sub Category
Soft Drinks $50k - 50% of total
Teas $50k - 50% of total

Brand
Coke $20k (How to show this as 20% OF TOTAL DRINKS instead of 40% of Soft Drinks)
Pepsi $10k
7-UP $10k

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate sales on a specific level by manipulating FILTER inside CALCULATE.
Here is an example:

```
%ofCategory = CALCULATE( DIVIDE(SUM('fact'[Val]), CALCULATE(SUM('fact'[Val]), ALL('fact'),'fact'[Category] = SELECTEDVALUE('fact'[Category]))))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks msta42a! however my product hierarchy is a bit different as the sub category is under the category. do you have any advice?

Comment: provide some dummy data and your desired output

Answer (score 0):

[Revenue per Drinks type Mix (%)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJj8z.png)

My Dax formula is this

Revenue per Drinks Type Mix =
IF(ISFILTERED(Sheet1[Drinks Type]),
DIVIDE(SUM(Sheet1[Revenue]),calculate(sum(Sheet1[Revenue]),ALLSELECTED(Sheet1[Revenue],Sheet1[Drinks Type]))),
DIVIDE(SUM(Sheet1[Revenue]),CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Revenue]),allselected(Sheet1[Revenue],Sheet1[Drinks Name]))))

Not sure why the [Drinks Name] showing 100% instead of the % of the Total [Drinks Type]

But ultimately, i would like to express the [Drinks Name] as a % of Total Revenue.

Please pardon me for the mistakes i may have made. Still a newbie here with Dax.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).